# How to retain 'by' function factor values

Tags: r, plot

If I have a by() that results in a list of numbers indexed by other numbers (not the natural numbers), and I want to take this result and plot it, the plotting will not plot the index numbers as x values, but instead will use 1:n instead. Is there anyway I can easy plot the values by their respective index values?
E.g.

source$time[values]: -9

[1] 0.015

---

source$time[values]: -5

[1] 0.013

---

source$time[values]: -4

[1] 0.003

....

In this case I would like to plot the .015, .013, and .003 as the y-axis and the -9,-5, and -4 as the x-axis.

Thanks!

Comment: Show us what you tried. "...plotting will not plot..." does not tell us what you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the the `rownames` function. In this case, you can plot like this:

`data.to.plot <- by(source,index,function)
plot(as.numeric(rownames(data.to.plot)),data.to.plot)`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps (assuming you set the value of the by-call to a name, say "object":

```
  plot( c(-9,-5, -4), sapply( object, "[[", as.character(c(-9,-5, -4))  ) )
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have the object is very large with many indices, so the c(a,b,c...) method does not seem feasible. Maybe I articulated poorly--sorry.

Comment: Sigh. Why not just `dput(object[1:3])`?